# The missing modules don't get installed after updating with Composer

Tags: 8, drush, composer

To update a site locally, I cloned the code base with git to my local computer and imported the database, then ran "composer update --with-dependencies", there were no errors, then I went to /web directory and ran "drush updb -y", it showed me 8 missing modules:

```
The following module is missing from the file system: add_to_head    [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: context        [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: context_ui     [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: libraries      [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: menu_target    [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: panelizer      [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: phpmailer      [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system: site_verify    [warning]
bootstrap.inc:276
The following module is missing from the file system:                [warning]
special_menu_items bootstrap.inc:276
No database updates required                                         [success]
```

I tried to log in to the local site, but first ran "drush pm-uninstall captcha", but the site returned the white screen and:

> "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

I thought that the problem was due to the missing modules and started running "composer require" for each of them. 
But they either didn't get installed or returned:

```
 Using version ^3.0@beta for drupal/phpmailer
./composer.json has been updated
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating drupal/phpmailer (dev-3.x 950f2af => 3.0.0-beta2):     Update failed (The .git directory is missing from web/modules/contrib/phpmailer, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing drupal/phpmailer (dev-3.x)
  - Installing drupal/phpmailer (3.0.0-beta2): Cloning 8.x-3.0-beta2 from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles
```

I don't what else to do. Is the "unexpected error" caused by those missing modules? What should I do to fix it?

UPDATE:
I looked at /admin/reports/dblog and here's the php error I saw:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route ""
>   does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()
>   (line 201 of
>   /sites/bak/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

Comment: Try to run `composer install` after composer require" for each of them.

Comment: if you don't need those modules you wanna just remove the warning, you can try `drush sql-query "DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='your_module';"`  for each of them .

Comment: composer install doesn't help. It returns "Nothing to install or update".
Also, when I ran "composer require drupal/add_to_head" and then "drush updb -y" it returned that add_to_head were still missing.

Comment: Do you see the modules in web/modules/contrib?

Answer (score 0):

I faced Same error before so what you have to do is 
for example let's say it is panelizer.

## The following module is missing from the file system: panelizer      [warning]bootstrap.inc:276

1) use composer and say composer require drupal/panelizer  in the terminal.

2)After installing the module now  try to uninstall the module right away using the command below

drush pm-uninstall panelizer

Now go to your site and do following operations.
Configuration>Development>Performance
and now do the Clear-Cache.
If you come back to your site you will not find an error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by executing the following steps:

- `composer clear-cache`
- `rm -r vendor/`
- `rm -r web/sites/modules/contrib`
- `composer install`

Answer (score -1):

Remove your Composer lock file and run following command in sequence:

- `composer clear-cache`
- `composer install`
- `composer require Drupal/module`

Answer (score -1):

Remove your Composer lock, vendor folder and run 'composer install' again